# How to set width of the floating div relative to neighbour

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a page which looks like this:
[image]

**Content** contains a static table of fixed width (determined by content) inside a centered div. Below content there is a div that contains a line of text and an image below that text. It is meant to float on the left of the **Content**. The page and image has max-width and max-height. But when page is resized, **Image** shrinks twice slower than the page. This causes the page to look like this:
[image]

I want **Image** to always be filling the most of that white gap on the left. When the page is resized, the **Image** should also resize accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4KG/

Html:

```
<section align="center">
    <h4 align="center">Heading</h4>
    <div align="center">
        <table>Content</table>
        <div id="image_box">
            <p align="left">Text above image</p>
            <img src="img.png" id="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Css:

```
#image_box {
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 0px;
    top: -75px;
    position: relative;
}

#image {
    float: left;
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code and/or link to a JS fiddle so we can better interpret what your desired result?  :)

Comment: @shekhardesigner http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4KG/ if you decrese "Result" width, you'll see SOf logo AND "Text above image", covering the green table.

Comment: What is "Result"? Are you referring to any selector or which elem?

Comment: @shekhardesigner The bottom-right box on JSFiddle page. Where the output of the code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

A few things before I'm able to fully comprehend what it is you're looking for.

It's strange how you're using the HTML5 `<section>` tag with a deprecated, and as of HTML5 removed, `align` attribute.  And still strange the use of an inline style when using css on those elements.

I will assume you're looking to center those elements within their parent containers.  To achieve this, you would need to use a set width and set the horizontal margin of the element to auto.

```
div {

  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

You also have a typo in your mark up. The DIV id says `imabe_box`. Assume it's supposed to be `image_box`.

```
<div align="center">
    <table>Content</table>
    <div id="imabe_box"> // ID should be set to 'image_box'
        <p align="left">Text above image</p>
        <img src="img.png" id="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please add more code or reply to the answer and we can help you further.

Comment: I have more compicated css with many more selectors, but adding align="center" takes out a portion of other properties.